# Git: possible to point subtree to different commits when switching branches?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-subtree

In a repository with two branches (master & develop) and a git subtree repository included in folder `shared`, is it possible to automatically synch the `shared` subtree to a specific version (commit) when changing branches?

My best guess is that I'm probably looking for a way to run a script whenever I change branches locally. The script then performs the necessary git pull/fetch commands on the subtree.

Let's say the master branch should always point to v1.0 tagged commit of the shared subtree repository, while the develop branch always checks out the latest commit. Edits to the shared subtree are only made in the develop branch and will be committed (or stashed) before switching to master.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have your subtrees in each branch point to different code versions. The state of the subtrees belong to the commit just like any other set of files, meaning that one branch can have different contents in the subtree from other branches. Upon checkout the state of the subtree will be updated with whatever is on that branch, again, just like any other file.

The simplest way to show this is to have a subtree in `master`, create a branch from `master`, and in the branch update the said subtree and commit. Thus the branch will have a modified version of the subtree, and if you check out `master` it will revert to the state previously left in `master`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled why this question has been abandoned for so long. I encountered the same problem in an SVN-Git migration, at the point of trying to reconstruct SVN "externals" dependencies.

Just to put another answer into the internet here, I think the way to go would be to create both a script calling `git fetch ...` and `git subtree pull ...` as well as a [post-checkout hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that executes this script. My idea is that the script would have the same name on every branch, so that the post-checkout hook would do nothing more than call `switch_dependency.py` or something, and you would manually have to take care of the correct commands in that script.